# import data from excel to sql server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, import, using

I want to import data from excel file to sql server using C# but the main issue is first I have to write code to create table.Is there any way by which first program read the first line of excel and create table on the basis of first row of excel sheet.Then I can use simple process of uploading data from excel. In simple words I want to create SQL data import wizard for excel file using C# .net. Problem is also because every time I got new excel sheet with different number of columns from which I have to import data in new database.

Comment: What is your question? Yes, you can read first line and create a table from it. You could insert one line at a time or using SQL Bulk Inserts... I am not really sure what your question is? The only answer is yes you can do all of the above but you need to code it yourself!

Comment: Yes it is possible what you said but you need to start working on it rather than asking us.It is better to try on your own and post your difficulty rather than asking for direct help it is better for everyone.